# C Program Giving Unexpected Output

Tags: c

I've been working on projects (not necessarily this one) for far too long tonight, and I am having a hard time with a program that I am writing for one of my classes. I've stared at it for long enough and have gotten nowhere, so I think it's time for another set (or a few sets) of eyes.

Eventually, the program will take an integer input, convert that to hex, and output the name of the language contained within a specific range of Unicode hex values. The hex values for said languages are contained within a text file (Blocks.txt) that we are required to use in our program.

This said, I haven't gotten that far, and am dealing with an intermediate issue. Right now, I am just trying to store all of the language names into a char[] field within an array of structures. The structure is one that I defined. I attempted to print all of the stored languages for testing purposes, but the output is not what I expect or desire.

What is printed to the console is correct, but the issue lies in what is not printed. The program stops about 40 lines short of the final language. I simply don't know why this is the case.

Another (probably) important thing. The first thing printed in the console is about 20 (definitely less than 40) blank lines.

Last thing, I apologize for my shitty disorganized rookie code. I am a beginner to C and I might go as far as to say that I have no idea what I am doing. Thanks to anyone who decides to help.

I will post my code, my output, and Blocks.txt below:

## My Code

```
//UnicodeBlocks.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
        int max;
        int min;
        char lang[300];
        //Contains a string holding hex ranges and a language.
        char lineinfo[300];
    } LoadData;

int main()
{
    LoadData data[300];
    char hexstring[300];
    int languagecount = 0;

    FILE *blocks;
    blocks = fopen("Blocks.txt", "r");
    if(blocks == NULL)
    {
        perror("Blocks.txt not found");
        return(-1);
    }

    //Store the hex value ranges and their affiliated
    //languages into data.allinfo.
    for(int i = 0; fgets(hexstring,100,blocks) != NULL; i++)
    {
        if(hexstring[0] != '\n' && hexstring[0] != '#')
                {
                    strcpy(data[i].lineinfo, hexstring);
                    languagecount++;
                }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < languagecount; i++)
    {
        char temp1[300];
        memset(temp1, 0, sizeof temp1);
        strcpy(temp1, data[i].lineinfo);

        for(int k = 0; k < strlen(temp1); k++)
        {
            char temp2[300];
            memset(temp2, 0, sizeof temp2);
            if(temp1[k] == ';')
            {
                k = k + 2;
                for(int j = 0; k < strlen(temp1); j++)
                {
                    temp2[j] = temp1[k];
                    k++;
                }
                strcpy(data[i].lang, temp2);
                //break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < languagecount; i++)
    {
        puts(data[i].lang);
    }

    fclose(blocks);

}
```

## My Output

```
//Insert about 20 blank lines here. I'm sure this is part of the issue, I     
//just don't know why

Basic Latin

Latin-1 Supplement

Latin Extended-A

Latin Extended-B

IPA Extensions

Spacing Modifier Letters

Combining Diacritical Marks

Greek and Coptic

Cyrillic

Cyrillic Supplement

Armenian

Hebrew

Arabic

Syriac

Arabic Supplement

Thaana

NKo

Samaritan

Mandaic

Arabic Extended-A

Devanagari

Bengali

Gurmukhi

Gujarati

Oriya

Tamil

Telugu

Kannada

Malayalam

Sinhala

Thai

Lao

Tibetan

Myanmar

Georgian

Hangul Jamo

Ethiopic

Ethiopic Supplement

Cherokee

Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics

Ogham

Runic

Tagalog

Hanunoo

Buhid

Tagbanwa

Khmer

Mongolian

Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics Extended

Limbu

Tai Le

New Tai Lue

Khmer Symbols

Buginese

Tai Tham

Combining Diacritical Marks Extended

Balinese

Sundanese

Batak

Lepcha

Ol Chiki

Sundanese Supplement

Vedic Extensions

Phonetic Extensions

Phonetic Extensions Supplement

Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement

Latin Extended Additional

Greek Extended

General Punctuation

Superscripts and Subscripts

Currency Symbols

Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols

Letterlike Symbols

Number Forms

Arrows

Mathematical Operators

Miscellaneous Technical

Control Pictures

Optical Character Recognition

Enclosed Alphanumerics

Box Drawing

Block Elements

Geometric Shapes

Miscellaneous Symbols

Dingbats

Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A

Supplemental Arrows-A

Braille Patterns

Supplemental Arrows-B

Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-B

Supplemental Mathematical Operators

Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows

Glagolitic

Latin Extended-C

Coptic

Georgian Supplement

Tifinagh

Ethiopic Extended

Cyrillic Extended-A

Supplemental Punctuation

CJK Radicals Supplement

Kangxi Radicals

Ideographic Description Characters

CJK Symbols and Punctuation

Hiragana

Katakana

Bopomofo

Hangul Compatibility Jamo

Kanbun

Bopomofo Extended

CJK Strokes

Katakana Phonetic Extensions

Enclosed CJK Letters and Months

CJK Compatibility

CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A

Yijing Hexagram Symbols

CJK Unified Ideographs

Yi Syllables

Yi Radicals

Lisu

Vai

Cyrillic Extended-B

Bamum

Modifier Tone Letters

Latin Extended-D

Syloti Nagri

Common Indic Number Forms

Phags-pa

Saurashtra

Devanagari Extended

Kayah Li

Rejang

Hangul Jamo Extended-A

Javanese

Myanmar Extended-B

Cham

Myanmar Extended-A

Tai Viet

Meetei Mayek Extensions

Ethiopic Extended-A

Latin Extended-E

Cherokee Supplement

Meetei Mayek

Hangul Syllables

Hangul Jamo Extended-B

High Surrogates

High Private Use Surrogates

Low Surrogates

Private Use Area

CJK Compatibility Ideographs

Alphabetic Presentation Forms

Arabic Presentation Forms-A

Variation Selectors

Vertical Forms

Combining Half Marks

CJK Compatibility Forms

Small Form Variants

Arabic Presentation Forms-B

Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms

Specials

Linear B Syllabary

Linear B Ideograms

Aegean Numbers

Ancient Greek Numbers

Ancient Symbols

Phaistos Disc

Lycian

Carian

Coptic Epact Numbers

Old Italic

Gothic

Old Permic

Ugaritic

Old Persian

Deseret

Shavian

Osmanya

Elbasan

Caucasian Albanian

Linear A

Cypriot Syllabary

Imperial Aramaic

Palmyrene

Nabataean

Hatran

Phoenician

Lydian

Meroitic Hieroglyphs

Meroitic Cursive

Kharoshthi

Old South Arabian

Old North Arabian

Manichaean

Avestan

Inscriptional Parthian

Inscriptional Pahlavi

Psalter Pahlavi

Old Turkic

Old Hungarian

Rumi Numeral Symbols

Brahmi

Kaithi

Sora Sompeng

Chakma

Mahajani

Sharada

Sinhala Archaic Numbers

Khojki

Multani

Khudawadi

Grantha

Tirhuta

Siddham

Modi

Takri

Ahom

Warang Citi

Pau Cin Hau

Cuneiform

Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation

Early Dynastic Cuneiform

Egyptian Hieroglyphs

Anatolian Hieroglyphs

Bamum Supplement

Mro

Bassa Vah

Pahawh Hmong

Miao
```

## Blocks.txt:

```
# Blocks-8.0.0.txt
# Date: 2014-11-10, 23:04:00 GMT [KW]
#
# Unicode Character Database
# Copyright (c) 1991-2014 Unicode, Inc.
# For terms of use, see http://www.unicode.org/terms_of_use.html
# For documentation, see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/
#
# Format:
# Start Code..End Code; Block Name

# ================================================

# Note:   When comparing block names, casing, whitespace, hyphens,
#         and underbars are ignored.
#         For example, "Latin Extended-A" and "latin extended a" are equivalent.
#         For more information on the comparison of property values, 
#            see UAX #44: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/
#
#  All block ranges start with a value where (cp MOD 16) = 0,
#  and end with a value where (cp MOD 16) = 15. In other words,
#  the last hexadecimal digit of the start of range is ...0 
#  and the last hexadecimal digit of the end of range is ...F.
#  This constraint on block ranges guarantees that allocations
#  are done in terms of whole columns, and that code chart display
#  never involves splitting columns in the charts.
#
#  All code points not explicitly listed for Block
#  have the value No_Block.

# Property: Block
#
# @missing: 0000..10FFFF; No_Block

0000..007F; Basic Latin
0080..00FF; Latin-1 Supplement
0100..017F; Latin Extended-A
0180..024F; Latin Extended-B
0250..02AF; IPA Extensions
02B0..02FF; Spacing Modifier Letters
0300..036F; Combining Diacritical Marks
0370..03FF; Greek and Coptic
0400..04FF; Cyrillic
0500..052F; Cyrillic Supplement
0530..058F; Armenian
0590..05FF; Hebrew
0600..06FF; Arabic
0700..074F; Syriac
0750..077F; Arabic Supplement
0780..07BF; Thaana
07C0..07FF; NKo
0800..083F; Samaritan
0840..085F; Mandaic
08A0..08FF; Arabic Extended-A
0900..097F; Devanagari
0980..09FF; Bengali
0A00..0A7F; Gurmukhi
0A80..0AFF; Gujarati
0B00..0B7F; Oriya
0B80..0BFF; Tamil
0C00..0C7F; Telugu
0C80..0CFF; Kannada
0D00..0D7F; Malayalam
0D80..0DFF; Sinhala
0E00..0E7F; Thai
0E80..0EFF; Lao
0F00..0FFF; Tibetan
1000..109F; Myanmar
10A0..10FF; Georgian
1100..11FF; Hangul Jamo
1200..137F; Ethiopic
1380..139F; Ethiopic Supplement
13A0..13FF; Cherokee
1400..167F; Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics
1680..169F; Ogham
16A0..16FF; Runic
1700..171F; Tagalog
1720..173F; Hanunoo
1740..175F; Buhid
1760..177F; Tagbanwa
1780..17FF; Khmer
1800..18AF; Mongolian
18B0..18FF; Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics Extended
1900..194F; Limbu
1950..197F; Tai Le
1980..19DF; New Tai Lue
19E0..19FF; Khmer Symbols
1A00..1A1F; Buginese
1A20..1AAF; Tai Tham
1AB0..1AFF; Combining Diacritical Marks Extended
1B00..1B7F; Balinese
1B80..1BBF; Sundanese
1BC0..1BFF; Batak
1C00..1C4F; Lepcha
1C50..1C7F; Ol Chiki
1CC0..1CCF; Sundanese Supplement
1CD0..1CFF; Vedic Extensions
1D00..1D7F; Phonetic Extensions
1D80..1DBF; Phonetic Extensions Supplement
1DC0..1DFF; Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement
1E00..1EFF; Latin Extended Additional
1F00..1FFF; Greek Extended
2000..206F; General Punctuation
2070..209F; Superscripts and Subscripts
20A0..20CF; Currency Symbols
20D0..20FF; Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols
2100..214F; Letterlike Symbols
2150..218F; Number Forms
2190..21FF; Arrows
2200..22FF; Mathematical Operators
2300..23FF; Miscellaneous Technical
2400..243F; Control Pictures
2440..245F; Optical Character Recognition
2460..24FF; Enclosed Alphanumerics
2500..257F; Box Drawing
2580..259F; Block Elements
25A0..25FF; Geometric Shapes
2600..26FF; Miscellaneous Symbols
2700..27BF; Dingbats
27C0..27EF; Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A
27F0..27FF; Supplemental Arrows-A
2800..28FF; Braille Patterns
2900..297F; Supplemental Arrows-B
2980..29FF; Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-B
2A00..2AFF; Supplemental Mathematical Operators
2B00..2BFF; Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows
2C00..2C5F; Glagolitic
2C60..2C7F; Latin Extended-C
2C80..2CFF; Coptic
2D00..2D2F; Georgian Supplement
2D30..2D7F; Tifinagh
2D80..2DDF; Ethiopic Extended
2DE0..2DFF; Cyrillic Extended-A
2E00..2E7F; Supplemental Punctuation
2E80..2EFF; CJK Radicals Supplement
2F00..2FDF; Kangxi Radicals
2FF0..2FFF; Ideographic Description Characters
3000..303F; CJK Symbols and Punctuation
3040..309F; Hiragana
30A0..30FF; Katakana
3100..312F; Bopomofo
3130..318F; Hangul Compatibility Jamo
3190..319F; Kanbun
31A0..31BF; Bopomofo Extended
31C0..31EF; CJK Strokes
31F0..31FF; Katakana Phonetic Extensions
3200..32FF; Enclosed CJK Letters and Months
3300..33FF; CJK Compatibility
3400..4DBF; CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A
4DC0..4DFF; Yijing Hexagram Symbols
4E00..9FFF; CJK Unified Ideographs
A000..A48F; Yi Syllables
A490..A4CF; Yi Radicals
A4D0..A4FF; Lisu
A500..A63F; Vai
A640..A69F; Cyrillic Extended-B
A6A0..A6FF; Bamum
A700..A71F; Modifier Tone Letters
A720..A7FF; Latin Extended-D
A800..A82F; Syloti Nagri
A830..A83F; Common Indic Number Forms
A840..A87F; Phags-pa
A880..A8DF; Saurashtra
A8E0..A8FF; Devanagari Extended
A900..A92F; Kayah Li
A930..A95F; Rejang
A960..A97F; Hangul Jamo Extended-A
A980..A9DF; Javanese
A9E0..A9FF; Myanmar Extended-B
AA00..AA5F; Cham
AA60..AA7F; Myanmar Extended-A
AA80..AADF; Tai Viet
AAE0..AAFF; Meetei Mayek Extensions
AB00..AB2F; Ethiopic Extended-A
AB30..AB6F; Latin Extended-E
AB70..ABBF; Cherokee Supplement
ABC0..ABFF; Meetei Mayek
AC00..D7AF; Hangul Syllables
D7B0..D7FF; Hangul Jamo Extended-B
D800..DB7F; High Surrogates
DB80..DBFF; High Private Use Surrogates
DC00..DFFF; Low Surrogates
E000..F8FF; Private Use Area
F900..FAFF; CJK Compatibility Ideographs
FB00..FB4F; Alphabetic Presentation Forms
FB50..FDFF; Arabic Presentation Forms-A
FE00..FE0F; Variation Selectors
FE10..FE1F; Vertical Forms
FE20..FE2F; Combining Half Marks
FE30..FE4F; CJK Compatibility Forms
FE50..FE6F; Small Form Variants
FE70..FEFF; Arabic Presentation Forms-B
FF00..FFEF; Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms
FFF0..FFFF; Specials
10000..1007F; Linear B Syllabary
10080..100FF; Linear B Ideograms
10100..1013F; Aegean Numbers
10140..1018F; Ancient Greek Numbers
10190..101CF; Ancient Symbols
101D0..101FF; Phaistos Disc
10280..1029F; Lycian
102A0..102DF; Carian
102E0..102FF; Coptic Epact Numbers
10300..1032F; Old Italic
10330..1034F; Gothic
10350..1037F; Old Permic
10380..1039F; Ugaritic
103A0..103DF; Old Persian
10400..1044F; Deseret
10450..1047F; Shavian
10480..104AF; Osmanya
10500..1052F; Elbasan
10530..1056F; Caucasian Albanian
10600..1077F; Linear A
10800..1083F; Cypriot Syllabary
10840..1085F; Imperial Aramaic
10860..1087F; Palmyrene
10880..108AF; Nabataean
108E0..108FF; Hatran
10900..1091F; Phoenician
10920..1093F; Lydian
10980..1099F; Meroitic Hieroglyphs
109A0..109FF; Meroitic Cursive
10A00..10A5F; Kharoshthi
10A60..10A7F; Old South Arabian
10A80..10A9F; Old North Arabian
10AC0..10AFF; Manichaean
10B00..10B3F; Avestan
10B40..10B5F; Inscriptional Parthian
10B60..10B7F; Inscriptional Pahlavi
10B80..10BAF; Psalter Pahlavi
10C00..10C4F; Old Turkic
10C80..10CFF; Old Hungarian
10E60..10E7F; Rumi Numeral Symbols
11000..1107F; Brahmi
11080..110CF; Kaithi
110D0..110FF; Sora Sompeng
11100..1114F; Chakma
11150..1117F; Mahajani
11180..111DF; Sharada
111E0..111FF; Sinhala Archaic Numbers
11200..1124F; Khojki
11280..112AF; Multani
112B0..112FF; Khudawadi
11300..1137F; Grantha
11480..114DF; Tirhuta
11580..115FF; Siddham
11600..1165F; Modi
11680..116CF; Takri
11700..1173F; Ahom
118A0..118FF; Warang Citi
11AC0..11AFF; Pau Cin Hau
12000..123FF; Cuneiform
12400..1247F; Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation
12480..1254F; Early Dynastic Cuneiform
13000..1342F; Egyptian Hieroglyphs
14400..1467F; Anatolian Hieroglyphs
16800..16A3F; Bamum Supplement
16A40..16A6F; Mro
16AD0..16AFF; Bassa Vah
16B00..16B8F; Pahawh Hmong
16F00..16F9F; Miao                 //This is where the output ends.
1B000..1B0FF; Kana Supplement
1BC00..1BC9F; Duployan
1BCA0..1BCAF; Shorthand Format Controls
1D000..1D0FF; Byzantine Musical Symbols
1D100..1D1FF; Musical Symbols
1D200..1D24F; Ancient Greek Musical Notation
1D300..1D35F; Tai Xuan Jing Symbols
1D360..1D37F; Counting Rod Numerals
1D400..1D7FF; Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols
1D800..1DAAF; Sutton SignWriting
1E800..1E8DF; Mende Kikakui
1EE00..1EEFF; Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols
1F000..1F02F; Mahjong Tiles
1F030..1F09F; Domino Tiles
1F0A0..1F0FF; Playing Cards
1F100..1F1FF; Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement
1F200..1F2FF; Enclosed Ideographic Supplement
1F300..1F5FF; Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
1F600..1F64F; Emoticons
1F650..1F67F; Ornamental Dingbats
1F680..1F6FF; Transport and Map Symbols
1F700..1F77F; Alchemical Symbols
1F780..1F7FF; Geometric Shapes Extended
1F800..1F8FF; Supplemental Arrows-C
1F900..1F9FF; Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
20000..2A6DF; CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B
2A700..2B73F; CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C
2B740..2B81F; CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D
2B820..2CEAF; CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E
2F800..2FA1F; CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement
E0000..E007F; Tags
E0100..E01EF; Variation Selectors Supplement
F0000..FFFFF; Supplementary Private Use Area-A
100000..10FFFF; Supplementary Private Use Area-B

# EOF
```

Comment: IS 300 enough lines to be loading?

Comment: Could you please make your story shorter and then state your main problem ? It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gaps in your `data` array. The first `for` loop always increments `i`. But not every iteration executes `strcpy(data[i].lineinfo, hexstring);`. That is, for each comment line in the input, your output `data` contains no data for that `i` value.

Try changing your first `for` loop to be something like below. The key change is to use `lanaguagecount` as the array index rather than `i`.

```
while (fgets(hexstring,100,blocks) != NULL)
{
    if(hexstring[0] != '\n' && hexstring[0] != '#')
    {
        strcpy(data[lanuagecount].lineinfo, hexstring);
        languagecount++;
    }
}
```

There are other issues with your code. Notably you need to protect more carefully against buffer overflows. But since your work is still in progress I will leave that as a task for you to complete.

Comment: Ahhh, fantastic. Makes so much sense now. Thank you so much.